# Wintouch Q75S - Removed wpa_supplicant on accident

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi

I removed the wpa_supplicant file and now the Wi-Fi doesn't work. Is there anyway to restore this file back? I tried Factory Reset but that only resets the apps and removes user data. The device is running on Android 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich.

Will flashing a new ROM fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only missing that one file, you could try using my copy of it:

http://www.freesoft.org/bbaccala/wpa_supplicant

I'm running 4.1.2, but I'll bet it'll work.

Comment: Be careful! What about binary compatibility with ICS 4.0.4 framework vs 4.1.2 JB framework....just saying!

Answer (score 0):

Flashing a new (or old, for that matter) ROM will fix your problem.

That's why they say to back things up before you mess with them ;)